# What happens if I beat Ganon in Zelda: Breath of the Wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I'm close to maxing out my character and I want to beat Ganon solely for the TRUE ending, but I'm too scared of losing some of my personal favorites from the Guardian Spear++ to fighting those damned Guardians (it was so fun).

So, after beating Ganon

1. **Do monsters disappear?** - Including the corrupted Guardians, but also the blood moons, I don't want to just face off against the Yiga Clan...
2. **Am I gonna run out of resources?** - As a survival game Zelda BOTW has some emphasis on the survival genre but to me it is a survival-esque action-adventure game.
3. **Are special weapons still available when you max out?** - Like the Savage Lynel Spears or Swords)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After you beat Ganon the game will reset to the last save before fighting him.

So all your weapons/resources will be returned as they were for that save. The only thing that will change is that you get a star after your savegame or in the menu(I forgot where) to indicate that you completed the game.

Ganon can be fought again if you want with the same result.

(Source is I did it myself)

Comment: So you mean to say is that Guardians stay corrupted,not run out of resources and I spawn back to where I was standing (sorry if my wording sucks) just for clarification

Comment: Whatever the status of the world was before you entered Ganon's castle, that is how the world will be when you fought him. Guardians usually respawn whenever there is a bloodmoon. And as far as i know, the only resources that are limited are chest. Everything else also respawns during blood moons

Comment: There is at least a couple other changes. Kilton will have new options when talking with him after you have beaten the game; and it will now track which minibosses you have defeated. You can earn rewards from him for killing all of them. Also, Symin will now sell you rare pictures for your compendium, including a picture of Ganon.

Comment: you even get a completion percentage! of how much you've done of the story and quests.